# how is jsonpath written in camel to select items in the json file

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, jsonpath

I have the following json file

```
 {  
       "name":"john",
       "address":"abcd",
       "ID":"xyz",
       "time":"2016-12-22"
    }
```

I want to send it from mock:a to mock:b only if ID = xyz in that jsonpath How is it done in camel ?

```
from("mock:a").choice().when().jsonpath("ID == xyz").to("mock:b") ?
```

How is the jsonpath part written ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found it -

```
.when().jsonpath("$.ID=='xyz'")
```

but the trick was to add the following dependency -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```